# Are there any CSS rules that, when set to empty strings, override lower-specificity rules

Tags: javascript, css, css-specificity

I'm trying to determine which style applies to an element by taking into account both inline and class styles. Javascript parses both of these into objects, but styles that are not set are empty strings, not `undefined`. If styles that are "empty" (e.g. `width:;`) have no effect, regardless of how specific the rule, then my goal is trivial.

However, in order to override `display:none` with the default rule dynamically, I know that `document.getElementById('ele').style.display = '';` works and, while I know it doesn't actually add a `display` inline style, are there any styles that do have an effect when set empty in CSS? If this is the case, I would have to parse the style and stylesheet strings manually to see if the property was defined.

Comment: `document.getElementById('ele').style.display = '';` works because you set `display:none;` to `display:;` which is invalid and hence the browser ignore  `display:;` and just uses the default display value. For `<div>` the default value is `display: block`, for  `<span>` it's `display: inline;` .

Comment: JavaScript doesn't parse anything, `.style` **are** the inline styles and the default value for properties is an empty string, which means "no inline style for this property".

Comment: @Sawny Not really. `.style.display = ''`  removes an existing inline style. Nothing is ignored.

Comment: @zeroflagL do you have a source that says empty string = "no inline style for this property" for all properties?

Comment: `width:;` is a syntax error and will be ignored no matter where it occurs. `elt.style.display = '';` does not set the value of the `display` property to an empty string, rather it removes the `display` property.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Either a property has a value or it doesn't. `style` is an implementation of the `CSS2Properties` interface.

Comment: @zeroflagL I was wondering if an empty string _is_ a valid property value that can override non-empty, less-specific rules. The comments suggests that clearly it isn't. To be clear: is the answer to this definitively no?

Comment: Just to be clear, if you say "empty string", you don't mean `''`, right? I mean, `content:''` is a valid style property. And then there's shorthand properties like `border`. The specs say all the values are optional; leaving out the width means `0`, leaving out the style means `none` and leaving out the color means `currentColor`. In other words, `border:;` would mean `border:0 none currentColor;` Nowhere does it say if that is valid or not though.

Comment: @MrLister Correct, I mean literally putting nothing between `:` and `;`. You bring up an interesting point, but when the class style is set, `border:;` isn't the same as `border:0 none currentColor;` ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a0zgc3uw/))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing `display:;` or `display:'';` within a stylesheet or style declaration block is an invalid declaration.

The `style` property of an element is a different story. It's a convenience mechanism to set and get the inline styles of an element. Setting a value is actually a shorthand for `.setProperty` and getting one a shorthand for `.getPropertyValue`.

```
<div></div>

=>
element.style.display == ''
element.getPropertyValue('display') == null
```

Since no inline style is set there is no value for `display`, so `getPropertyValue('display')` returns `null`.

Now that we know that`.display` is short for `.getPropertyValue('display')` let's look what the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSStyleDeclaration) says about the returned value:

> Returns the value of the property if it has been explicitly set for this declaration block. Returns the empty string if the property has not been set

So empty string equals no value.

```
element.style.display = 'none'

=>
<div style="display: none;"></div>
element.getPropertyValue('display') == 'none'
```

As you can see we can easily set an inline style using `.style`. If we now try to set an invalid value it will be ignored:

```
element.style.display = 'foo'

=>
<div style="display: none;"></div>
element.getPropertyValue('display') == 'none'
```

Nothing changes. Setting the value to an empty string works though, as it is equivalent to no style:

```
element.style.display = ''

=>
<div></div>
element.getPropertyValue('display') == null
```

Setting `display` to `null` would work too.